# Get default ruby back

Tags: homebrew, macos

I'm in the process of setting up my Ruby on Rails development environment and part of that was playing around with RVM. I screwed up a bit though because I deleted the /usr/local/bin/ruby which was required for homebrew.

How can I get that version of ruby back at this point?

Comment: I think you might be confused. There is no standard ruby in `/usr/local/bin/` do you mean `/usr/bin/` ?

Comment: You're right. I meant /usr/bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://superuser.com/questions/171433/is-it-possible-to-reinstall-fix-mac-os-xs-system-ruby-without-doing-a-complete-o